# PHP push multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting

I got some data from mySQL (Name & Score) and want so push it into an array so I can sort it.

```
$stack = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $db_erg, MYSQLI_BOTH))
    {
      $stack_data = array($row['Name'] => $row['Score']);
      array_push($stack, $stack_data);
    }
     //asort($stack);
     print_r($stack);
```

I didn't work to sort it. And when I print my $stack Array it looks like this:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [Nina] => 94 ) [1] => Array ( [Tina] => 50 ) [2] => Array ( [Tim] => 50 ) [3] => Array ( [Anton] => 50 ) [4] => Array ( [Jim] => 50 ) [5] => Array ( [Tom] => 50 ) [6] => Array ( [Ed] => 50 ) [7] => Array ( [Bob] => 50 ) )

Comment: sort by which key ?

Comment: Why not just add `order by Score` in your query!!

Comment: Whereever possible let MYSQL do all the heavy lifting.

Comment: I would up click RiggsFolly all day long! +100! PHP or any programming language array sorting is the last thing to do if the query is 100% not possible in  your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the sorting with your query:

```
SELECT `Name`,`Score` FROM `[tablename]` WHERE `Score`>=50 ORDER BY `Score` DESC,`Name`
```